# I am getting this exception while I am trying to check whether the email exist in record or not"FormatException: Unexpected character (at character1)"

Tags: flutter, api

```
FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter ( 8510): <br />
I/flutter ( 8510): ^
```

```
validateUserEmail()async{

    try{
      var res= await http.post(
        Uri.parse(API.validateEmail),
        body: {
          'user_email':emailController.text.trim(),
      }
      );
      print(res.statusCode);
      if(res.statusCode==200){
        var resBodyOfValidateEmail= jsonDecode(res.body);
        print(resBodyOfValidateEmail);
        if(resBodyOfValidateEmail['emailFound'] == true){
          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Email already Exist");
        }
        else{
          registerAndSaveUserRecord();
        }
      }
    }
    catch(e){
      print(e.toString()+"catch block");

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

That error happens when you put a string in `jsonDecode` that's not valid JSON. It means that `res.body` is not valid JSON. Maybe try printing `res.body` before you use `jsonDecode` to see it.

Comment: Thank you so much sir there was an error in json file now it's working